# Dual boot. two bootable ssd's, Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10 Pro

Tags: dual-boot, windows, xubuntu

I had a single Ubuntu 16.04 system on one ssd. I added a second ssd, unhooked the first ssd, then did a clean new install of Windows 10 Pro. Both boot fine with Ubuntu being set in bios as the first OS to load. If i want Windows instead i just go into bios and pick it to load. All this works fine but i thought there maybe and easy way to have a screen like grub come up to let me choose which OS instead of going into bios.

Comment: Have you done `update-grub2` in Ubuntu yet?

Comment: No i have not. Please advise. Any bad side effects since this is not the way peaple do dual boots

Comment: grub is the preferred method for dual boot and is already installed on your system. just boot ubuntu and type in a terminal `sudo update-grub`

Comment: @Mark what do you mean by that? I consider that one of the best methods to create a multi-boot. feldspar is correct though: you need to tell the bootloader (grub) to add all the possible bootable systems.

Comment: Worked! Used sudo update-grub2.